# How to make sure to have fresh copy of files after each release of application (my website ) to the end user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser-cache, iis-8

I am having really some strange issue for js,images & css files related to caching.

I am using IIS 8.5 & asp.net MVC for my application, to overcome cache issue after each production release i have added version in web config and i use it mention below way. (for some common files i m using bundling)

**web.config**

```
<add key="Config.Version" value="1.0.0.0.65" />

<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
```

**some.cshtml**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/somefolder/some.js?v=" + Config.Version)" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have also **enabled dynamic compression** in IIS.

I wants to make sure after each **Release /Publish** of the application, The end user /client side update files should be loaded instated of older one.
(Here issue is that even though sever has latest updated files some time client needs to hard refresh(ctrl + F5) or similar techniques ).

My main question how can i make sure each time everyone gets the latest file version.

> Note: I also don't want to compromise with cache to get performance.
>
> Can anyone show me best practice or general guideline for this ?

Comment: `BundleConfig` and Bundle mechanism created for this. Don't you want to use it?

Comment: You can add a cache expiry date to all the static resources (css,js,images) of your application. Set it to a small value (5 mins). Like this even if the cache is stored it wont be used as it is expired.

Comment: I also wants some solid solution for this,,

Answer (score 1):

Adding a query string param is enough to invalidate all client-side caching. Based on the HTTP spec, the query string is part of the URL and any change makes it a *completely different* URL. A browser that didn't reload the CSS/scripts would be broken. I know of no major browser that wouldn't reload, though.

One thing to consider, however, is that the HTML page itself may be getting cached. If the client is just loading the old HTML, then the old reference to the CSS/scripts is the same and are also loaded from cache. Make sure you're not allowing HTML documents to be cached if you want to ensure that the user always gets the latest version.

Comment: can we also make some mechanism that if we have new copy on server for document then only it goes to get latest one else cached document can be used. Is there any ?

Comment: Not for HTML pages. It would require something like the cache-busting query param used with CSS and scripts, but for the HTML page, that would make it part of the URL for the actual document which would create a potential host of issues. Sending the HTML is nothing, in terms of request size, assuming you don't have crazy huge HTML pages a la Frontpage (once saw one that was 28MB of *just* HTML) in the days of old. Average HTML weight is about 5-10K, which is nothing, even on a mobile, metered connection.